# Listar en Datatable.js 12k de filas

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter-3, datatable

Estoy trabajando con php y mysql con el framework Codeigniter y estoy cargando en una lista 12 mil registros de productos utilizando Datatable.js, el problema esque cuando se muestra la pagina me cargan los 12 mil registros y despues de unos 20 seg se acomoda, osea se encuadra la lista y se muestra los numeros de paginacion.

Como hago para que no cargue los 12 mil? si no solo los 10 o 20 primeros nada mas, después ya con la interacción del usuario ya cargue el resto.

```
$(document).ready(function() {          

    $('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Buscar '+title+'" />' );
    } );


    var table = $('#example').DataTable();



        table.columns().every( function () {
            var that = this;

            $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
                if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                    that
                        .search( this.value )
                        .draw();
                }
            } );
        } );
    } );

   $('#example').DataTable( {
    "language": {
        "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
        "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
        "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
        "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
        "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
        "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
        "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
        "sInfoPostFix":    "",
        "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
        "sUrl":            "",
        "sInfoThousands":  ",",
        "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",            
        "oPaginate": {
            "sFirst":    "Primero",
            "sLast":     "Último",
            "sNext":     "Siguiente",
            "sPrevious": "Anterior"
        },
        "oAria": {
            "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
            "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
        }
    }       

} );
```

Comment: Tienes que utilizar server-side processing con Ajax, aqui la documentacion: https://datatables.net/manual/server-side

Comment: Gracias, voy a probarlo

Comment: Puede que el término que busques es "lazy loading" que se refiere justo a lo que comenta @alanfcm. Aquí puedes encontrar un ejemplo de como implementarlo: [Lazy loading](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/pipeline.html)